# PC shutting down every 30 minutes

Tags: cpu, power-supply

I changed my graphics card and PSU today (went from 650Ti to GTX 770 and Thermaltake PurePower 430W to OCZ GameXStream 600W). I plugged these components in, at first I didn't fit the 20+4 pin motherboard connector properly (the 4 separate pins weren't settled all the way in), but I shut my PC down as soon as it started making repeated beeping noises and corrected my mistake. The PC ran fine after that and the card is running very nicely. I ran Furmark and Unigine Heaven on it and it didn't break a sweat.

Now the problem is that my PC is shutting off by itself every 30 minutes. I thought it was the Windows so I let my PC sit on BIOS screen for 30 minutes and same, it shut off around 30 minutes. So it's definitely not the windows.

I've also checked temperatures and all temperatures were around 40 degree Celsius at least twice the times this happened. So I've ruled out high temperatures too.

What's confusing me is that the PC is rock stable during those 30 minutes, I can run Furmark. Do all graphics/processor intensive work during that time, but at the end, even if the PC is sitting idle it would turn off by itself. I'm listing my complete PC specs below:

- Processor: Intel Core i5 4430 @ 3.0 GHz
- MB: Gigabyte H81M-DS2
- RAM: 16GB Kingston (8x2)
- GPU: Asus GTX 770
- PSU: OCZ GameXStream 600W

I want to know how can I find the culprit component of this issue and replace/fix it.

Comment: When you're in BIOS, can you switch to the system health page (if it exists) and watch it?

Comment: Try to check windows event viewer after it shutdowns